# Jquery/ hover and change img

Tags: jquery, html

I use the next, in order to change the picture, when I hover the image:

```
<img id="image1" src="imimage.jpg" alt="facebook.com">

$('#image1').hover(function() {
    $('#image1').attr('src', 'imanewimage.jpg');
}, function() { 
    $('#image1').attr('src', 'imimage.jpg'); 
});
```

But something really weird happens: When I load the HTML, the imimage.jpg loaded. But when I hover it, the imimage.jpg doesn't load and only the alt attribute is shown.

What can be the reason?

Comment: @MohammadAdil: Yes, I correct it

Comment: Does the Imanewimage.jpg show up?

Comment: Also, on a side note, you should use prop() instead of attr(), which is deprecated.

Comment: @tymeJV: No. But when I use img from the net (*/http://www...*/) is shown

Comment: are you sure, your images are at correct path ?

Comment: @MohammadAdil: Yes, and as I said, when I inital my page with 'imimage.jpg', I can see the image

Comment: @RomainBraun -- `.attr()` is not deprecated, it is still used. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15070277/why-jquery-1-9-attr-method-not-deprecated

Comment: _But when I hover it, the imimage.jpg doesn't load and only the alt attribute is shown_.. that mean's your original image isn't available/accessible.

Comment: @MohammadAdil: So how it available when I load my page? Again, I can see the image before I hover it, and the src is the same

Comment: @TomAvni  See it here working --> http://jsfiddle.net/mohammadAdil/LWteu/3/

Comment: @tymeJV Well in this case, there's no reason to use attr().

Answer (score 1):

Your code above is correct, the alt tag is showing because the image most likely isn't in the proper location. Based on your code, the image should be in the same directory as your pages.

Test this with images from the internet (you said they are working), must be a file location issue.

Comment: I don't think it file location issue, because as I said, I can see the image before I hover it. and the src is the same.

Answer (score 0):

You could simplify this by using css to change the image instead of javascript, which would make it more universally compatible and easier to code...

```
<div class='imageToHover'></div>

.imageToHover {
   /*you probably want some height/width stuff in here too*/
   background-image: url(imimage.jpg);
}
.imageToHover:hover {
   background-image: url(imanewimage.jpg);
}
```