# jQuery change div ID from x to y

Tags: jquery, if-statement

using jQuery I would like to change the ID one of element within a page, a div, and give it a new one.  I **cannot** use classes, must be ID.  This will be part of an IF statement, for example: (pseudo:)

if x = greater than 1, change id of x to y
else
do nothing

So far I have:

```
$('#carriage-promo').attr('id','#carriage-promo-2');
```

However, this doesn't seem to work.  Any suggestions?

I've never worked with ID, always class, and I **would** have used addClass and removeClass, which have always worked for me in the past!

Comment: change #carriage-promo-2 to carriage-promo-2(removed #) and try

Comment: Got this all working now - thanks everyone for the great answers. :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$('#carriage-promo').attr('id','#carriage-promo-2');
```

No need of `#`.  So remove it

```
$('#carriage-promo').attr('id','carriage-promo-2');
```

---

or you can use **[.prop()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr)**

```
$('#carriage-promo').prop('id','carriage-promo-2');
```

See the perform test case in [**jsperf**](http://jsperf.com/this-attr-id-vs-this-prop-id)

Here is a sample [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/e2wFK/3/)

Comment: In this case, would you use `attr` or `prop`?  Can you explain?

Comment: @Archer Sure, performance matter.  check this http://jsperf.com/this-attr-id-vs-this-prop-id

Comment: @Archer http://api.jquery.com/prop/

I don't fully understand the difference myself, however prop seems to be working, whereas attr did not.

Comment: @Myles I'm not sure why `.attr` didn't work. Check this http://jsfiddle.net/e2wFK/3/

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
$('#carriage-promo').attr('id','carriage-promo-2');
```

Comment: is there any difference in your answer from the above posted one?

Comment: ohh :) good one but i didn't mean that. I just wanted to know why are you writing the same answer that already given.

Answer (score 1):

Just apply the String you want to update.

```
$('#carriage-promo').attr('id','carriage-promo-2');
```

Why because  `'#'`  is to select the element, with perticular `Id`

ID  is  DOM specific and `#`  is Jquery specific.

Answer (score 1):

No need of `#`, just use the id:

```
$('#carriage-promo').attr('id','carriage-promo-2');
```

Better use `prop()`. There have been some [changes with `attr()` and `prop()` from Jquery v1.6 onwards](http://api.jquery.com/prop/#prop-propertyName):

```
$('#carriage-promo').prop('id','carriage-promo-2');
```

`prop()` is for Properties and `attr()` is for Attributes.

Comment: `.attr()` is not depreciated. Check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/15070342/1671639