# How to get the inner span id using JQuery

Tags: jquery

I use the following code.

```
<div class="tt-suggestion">
    <p style="white-space: normal;">
        <span id="1">Rajesh<span style="float:right;">Bangalore</span>
        </span>
    </p>
</div>
```

When i click on , i need to have inner  id.Below is my code to get the span id

```
$(document).on('click', '.tt-suggestion', function(){
var id=$(this).find("span").id;
});
```

How many values get from the database that many number of times that  repeats. When i click on that , if i get the  id, I have to send that  id as a parameter to other php using ajax.But i am not able to get the  id. Can anyone please help on this,Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll have to use [`attr` (doc link)](https://api.jquery.com/attr/), since jQuery objects do not have an `id` property:

```
$(document).on('click', '.tt-suggestion', function(){
    var id = $('span', this).attr('id');
});
```

I've also removed the call to `find` to replace it with a more elegant form, although that's of course my opinion and not completely necessary.

Comment: .attr() is deprecated; use .prop() is recommended.

Comment: 1+ Beat me.. or you can use `$('span', this)[0].id`.

Comment: @frenchie Huh? Since when is `attr` deprecated?

Comment: read here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15070277/why-jquery-1-9-attr-method-not-deprecated

Comment: you're right, attr() is not deprecated but it's not the best way to do it: prop() is better

Answer (score 0):

simply you can call the function attr to get any element attribute value

```
$(document).on('click', '.tt-suggestion', function(){
var id=$(this).find("span").attr('id');
    alert(id);
});
```

you can test you code here
https://jsfiddle.net/qumop5pk/

Answer (score 0):

Really simple call this function and you will get it... try ;-)

```
$('span').click(function (){

var Id=$(this).attr('id');

alert(Id);

});
```